# Read mercurial repository from PHP

Tags: php, mercurial

I want to be able to take a file in a Mercurial repository (Readme for example) and display it to the user.
Is this possible in PHP? I do have command line hg installed on the server.

Comment: I don't know whether there are any PHP connectors to Mercurial, but you could always interact with hg on the command line, couldn't you?

Comment: @Pekka: Yeah, I'm pretty sure I can use hg from PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just launch `hg cat -r <rev> file` from php, you'll get the file in stdout.

Comment: -r 'tip' always gets the most recent changeset

Answer (score 0):

Maybe running

```
hg serve
```

and interacting with the server (localhost:8000) could be a viable option.

Comment: On a shared host, so I can't do this.